# Parsing different formatted date strings

Tags: ruby, datetime, datetime-format

I am working on writing a helper to parse some date strings that I have been given in a CSV. The problem is they are not consistent in the way that they are formatted. There are three different formats:

- "01021992" (`%m%d%Y`)
- "19920201" (`"%Y%m%d"`)
- "PORSCHE" (or some other random word)

Below is the function that I have written to help me parse the dates.

```
class DateTimeParser
  require "date"
  require 'active_support/all'
  require 'byebug'

  class Object
    def blank?
      return self == nil || self == ""
    end
  end

  def parse_string_date
    date_str = "01021992"
    formats = ["%Y%m%d", "%m%d%Y"]
    date = nil

    formats.each do |form|
      begin
        date =  DateTime.parse(date_str, form)
        break
      rescue => e
        puts "ERROR: #{e}"
        puts "Failed for #{date_str} with format #{form}"
      end
    end

    #this should handle the case where the date is just a word (i.e. "PORSCHE")
    if date.nil?
      date = DateTime.parse("03141994", "%m%d%Y")
    end

    date = date.change(:offset => "+0500")
    puts "Date : #{date}"
  end

  DateTimeParser.new().parse_string_date
end
```

Possible inputs were provided above if you want to run this and change the value of `date_str`

**OUTPUT:**

```
ERROR: invalid date
Failed for 01021992 with format %Y%m%d
ERROR: invalid date
Failed for 01021992 with format %m%d%Y
```

I guess my trouble is I can't seem to determine what the proper formats are that you can pass to `parse`.

Comment: Instead of `DateTime.parse(date_str, form)` Try `DateTime.strptime(date_str, form)`

Comment: you also need to modify the logic in `format.each do ....` since one of the two `formats` will parse successfully for one `date_str`. Try to change the order of `formats` to see that `parse_string_date` indeed successfully parses the `date_str` if `%m%d%Y` is the first element

Comment: @ImranAli Thanks for your help. It looks like this is going to work!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of randomly trying things, why not establish some patterns and templates:

```
FORMATS = {
  /\A(19|20)\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\z/ => '%Y%m%d',
  /\A\d{2}\d{2}(19|20)\d{2}\z/ => '%m%d%Y'
}
```

Then you can try decoding this way:

```
format = FORMATS.find do |rx, _|
  rx.match(date_str)
end

format and DateTime.parse(date_str, format[1])
```

You can add other formats to that, plus a "whatever" condition where you give up and return the string as-is.